# Sveltekit redirect is not working from server side function

Tags: javascript, redirect, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I've got a svelte `Header` component. In this component there's a `logout` button. When the button is clicked a function is invoked and this function calls a server side function. In this function I've got a redirect statement that doesn't seem to work.

Here's part of the component (pasting only relevant code):

```
<script>

    /**
     * Logs out the current user.
     * @returns {Promise<void>}
     */
    const logout = async () => {

        // call to internal API to perform logout.
        const response = await fetch("/api/user-logout", {
            method: "POST",
        });
    }

</script>

<header>
<!-- Logout -->
            <div class="tooltip tooltip-left" data-tip="Log out">
                <button
                        on:click={logout}
                        class="relative p-2 text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-600 focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-600 rounded-full"
                >
                    <span class="sr-only">Log out</span>
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor"
                         viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path d="M17 16l4-4m0 0l-4-4m4 4H7m6 4v1a3 3 0 01-3 3H6a3 3 0 01-3-3V7a3 3 0 013-3h4a3 3 0 013 3v1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                              stroke-width="2"/>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
</header>
```

Here's `api/user-logout/+server.js`:

```
import { redirect } from "@sveltejs/kit";

export async function POST({ request, fetch, cookies, event}) {

    // remove the auth cookie.
    // cookies.delete(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, { path: '/' });

    // redirect user to login page.
    throw redirect(302, '/login');
}
```

The above function is being hit for sure as I added some log statements and they are being printed but the redirect never happens.

I also tried using only `redirect(302, '/login')` as I'm using sveltekit 2.5 but didn't work.

I made it work by returning a response from `api/user-logout/+server.js` and then using `goto` in the frontend function:

```
const logout = async () => {

        // call to internal API to perform logout.
        const response = await fetch("/api/user-logout", {
            method: "POST",
        });

        if (await response.status == 200) {
             await goto("/login")
        }
    }
```

It works but I'd rather have the redirect from `api/user-logout/+server.js`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

it's a normal behavior as you are using FETCH and then you must handle it response to continue your flow. What you are expecting is the browser automatically redirect to **/login**, to have this behavior you should rather have a **/logout** page with it **+page.server.js**

Then the load function will `redirect(307, '/login')` after correctly cleaning the cookie.
In that case your button can be just an `<a href="/logout">`, and that moment your redirect will work as you expect.